# How do I properly override a constrained method

Tags: f#, type-constraints

How do I override the method `Zero` in the following code in such a way that I can return `Euro(0)` for the definiton in the `type Euro`

```
[<AbstractClass>] 
type Currency () =
    abstract member Zero<'T when 'T :> Currency > : unit -> 'T

type Euro (value: int) =
    inherit Currency()
    member this.Value = value
    override this.Zero() = Euro(0) :> _
```

Comment: `Zero` is a generic method and needs to return a value for any subtype of `Currency` the caller chooses so you can't fix it within your `Euro` type. At the moment a caller could do `let c = new Euro(0) :> Currency; c.Zero<Dollar>()`. Can you move `T` to the `Currency` class?

Comment: Isnt this for all practical purpose a DU? No?

Comment: @HelgeReneUrholm: No, in this case there's an open universe of types. You lose exhaustive matches, but can add new subtypes without recompiling (or in other files/assemblies, etc...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried lifting the generic constraint to the class level?

```
[<AbstractClass>] 
type Currency<'T when 'T :> Currency<'T>>() =
    abstract member Zero : unit -> 'T

type Euro (value: int) =
    inherit Currency<Euro>()
    member this.Value = value
    override this.Zero() = Euro(0)
```

Though self-referencing generics always seems weird to me, this is how it'd be done in, for example, C#.

Comment: Oh my goodness. I am fainting!
Thanks thou. PS: I have another solution too.

Comment: Coolio... what's the alternative solution? Make the member static and forgo the inheritance?

Comment: @pblasucci fwiw, I've added another solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the 'roll your own typeclass' technique in F#. Basically your abstract type's (instance and static) members become the fields of a 'typeclass' record, and values of that record are typeclass instances. You can have a 'euro' instance, a 'dollar' instance, and so on:

```
module Currency =
  type t<[<Measure>] 'a> =
    { zero : decimal<'a>; from : decimal -> decimal<'a> }

  /// Helper function to easily create typeclass instances for any
  /// currency.
  let make<[<Measure>] 'a> (curr_unit : decimal<'a>) : t<'a> =
    { zero = curr_unit - curr_unit; from = ((*) curr_unit) }

  [<Measure>] type euro
  let euro : t<euro> = make 1m<euro>

  [<Measure>] type dollar
  let dollar : t<dollar> = make 1m<dollar>
```

The unique thing about F# is that the type parameter that is passed to each typeclass instance can actually be a measure type, which is appropriate for currencies.

Comment: This OK as long as you dont want to put those different types into a generic list

Comment: @robkuz: I would have gone with units-of-measure in the first place, but your application requires to put different currencies into one list, is that correct?

Comment: @AntonSchwaighofer yup

Comment: @robkuz I may be confused here, but I haven't been able to put them in a generic list with Paulmichael's technique either. If the currencies are lifted to the type, you can't put them in the same list, no matter what specific technique you use.

Comment: nope you can't. Something I realized only later thou :-(